# shoulda-matcher error validating length_of

Tags: activerecord, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails, shoulda

I'm writing some specs for my User model but the tests are not passing. I'm fallowing [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#ensure_length_of) from the github page of the gem without success. This is my code:

```
validates :phone, numericality: { only_integer: true }, allow_blank: true, length: { is: 7 }
validates :mobile, numericality: { only_integer: true }, allow_blank: true, length: { is: 10 }
```

and my specs

```
it { should ensure_length_of(:phone).is_equal_to(7) }
it { should ensure_length_of(:mobile).is_equal_to(10) }
```

This validations should only run during the update process.

The errors:

Did not expect errors to include "longitud errónea (debe ser de 7 caracteres)" when telefono is set to "xxxxxxx", got error: longitud errónea (debe ser 
de 7 caracteres)

Did not expect errors to include "longitud errónea (debe ser de 10 caracteres)" when celular is set to "xxxxxxxxxx", got error: longitud errónea (debe s
er de 10 caracteres)

FYI: I've set Spanish Locales; I think this is the cause

Hope someone could help me. Thanks is advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the error because shoulda_matcher does not expect that `length: { is: 7 }` is used with `numericality`.

PS as for me - it is strange to use numeric for phone numbers, you can use string and use `validates` with `format` to be sure in validness data. For example email validation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates)

Comment: thanks @gotva. I'm new to rails and I thought that phone and mobile number validations must me with numericality. I've fond something for future readers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation